# HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() blocks

Tags: java

I'm using the HttpURLConnection class to make http requests.
My code looks something like this-

```
while(true){
    try{
         connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
         connection.setDoOutput(true);
         connection.setConnectTimeout(2*1000);
         InputStream in=connection.getInputStream();
    }
    catch(SocketTimeOutException e){}
    catch(IOException e){}
}
```

I do some processing on the data once I retrieve the InputStream object. My problem is that if  I let the program run long enough, the call to getInputStream blocks and I never get past that.

 Am I missing something? Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Never do this kind of thing `catch(SocketTimeOutException e){}` in a `while(true)` loop. It will make it very hard to debug or stop your program gracefully.

Comment: @artbristol what are you trying to say ... that's from our production code :)

Comment: Apart from doing as @artbristol says have you tried commenting out the  `connection.setDoOutput(true)` as this means it is expecting you to call `connection.getOutputStream()` and write something in the Http body

Comment: Hi @artbristol- Thanks for your comment. What would be a good way to structure this code then? My requirement is that I don't care what exception occurs. I just keep reading data from the URL and when I do get some data, I use it.

Comment: @GarethDavis- Oh. Yes. My bad. I fixed that in my code. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Why would you set a connect timeout and then ignore a timeout exception? Beats me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the read time out for the connection.
Also, close the streams in a finally block once you're done with them.

Answer (score 1):

You should close connections that are not used. Here is example:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(2*1000);
connection.connect();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
 stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
}
String result = stringBuilder.toString();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Setting a read time out on the connection seemed to fix it! Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: GET with setDoOutput(true) does not work well together.