# How do HttpURLConnection in Java Modern Batch

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to make a Java Modern Batch.
Everything works regularly: the job starts and ends until I insert in the method "Initialize" of step a call "HttpURLConnection".
With the HTTP call the execution remains blocked and I have to restart the server every time.

This is the code of HttpURLConnection:

```
String url = "http://mywebsite.com/api.xml";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

try {
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}   
isr.close();
in.close();     
connection.disconnect();

String xml = response.toString();
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to read the input unless the response code is success.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worthwhile looking at this SO thread ([HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705240/httpurlconnection-getinputstream-blocks)) . You can try setting a read timeout in the code and see if that helps you come out of the "block" happening.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestion did not solve the problem.
Thanks anyway!